# Is ideal clear pulling lube okay for pvc conduit

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit, lubrication

I'm pulling NM 6 gauge 3 conductor (plus ground) through a 1 inch pvc conduit.  I'm wondering if Ideal Clear pulling lube is okay.  It says it's okay for all wiring types, but not if it's okay for all conduits.  Ideal 77 says it's okay for pvc but not for low-density polyethylene and semi-conducting jackets.  I'm not sure what kind of jacket my NM 6-3 wire has.

Comment: This is an indoor conduit sleeve, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is indoors.  I'm using conduit because the wire has to run on the outside of a masonry wall.  It's for a stove.

Comment: understood then, NP

Comment: Given what is said about it in Ideal's blurb, I expect it to be fine. The PVC mentioned in the other lubricant is wire insulation type (as are the things it's not compatible with - pretty much any pulling lube that was not compatible with PVC conduit would need a huge warning to that effect. Likewise, all wiring types do include PVC wire insulation.

Comment: @Eric the outside of the masonry wall is indoors?

Comment: Yes, it's indoors as far as the house goes, it's outside as opposed to inside the wall.